# Overlapping of Sections/Div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hello guys I made menu using `flexbox` and defined hero image in `CSS` everything working fine, but when I want add another section under image using `flexbox`, It show's over that first one. I need to show it under first section(as default behaviors is). I tried to define positions, but I made so many changes there and now I'm confused so I need your help to find right way.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:600&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:500&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kalam:700&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

li,a {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.logo {
    font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
    color: aliceblue;
}

header { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 30px 10%;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.hero{
    background-image:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0, 0.52), rgba(0,0,0, 0.5)),
    url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/31/19/29/schnitzel-3279045_960_720.jpg');
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;

}
.text  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}
h1.title {
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: "Kalam",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 5rem;
}
h3.podnadpis {
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

button {
    background: none;
    border: 2px solid;
    font: inherit;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
button {
        color: var(--color);
        transition: 0.25s;
  }
  button:hover, button:focus {
    border-color: var(--hover);
    color: #000;
    background-color: #e5ff60;
  }
.raise:hover,
.raise:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0.5em 0.5em -0.4em #e5ff60;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.25em);
          transform: translateY(-0.25em);
}
.raise {
    --color: #ffa260;
    --hover: #e5ff60;
  }
li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

li a {
    transition: all 0.3 ease 0s;
}

li a:hover { 
    color: green;
}

section.about {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 30px 10%;
}
p {
    color: #000;
}
.divider {
    width: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100px;

}

.left {
    width: 45%;
    height: auto;
}

.right {
    width: 45%;
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Restaurant</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hero">
            <div class="text">
            <h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum</h1>
            <h3 class="podnadpis">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h3>
            <button class="raise">Lorem ipsum</button>
        </div>
    </div>
<header>     
    <div class="logo"><a href="#"><h1>Restaurant</h1></a></div>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav__link">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>  
<section class="about">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="right"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text evesince the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p> </div>
</section>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Začal bych tím, že header budeš mít absolutně pozicovaný, div hero dej relativně pozicovaný ale obrázek nedej na pozadí, ale jako img nebo jako pozadí ale nastav výšku ručně a to je naprd.. takže místo background ho dej jako img tag... klidně ti to tak upravím jestli chceš do odpovědi. :)

Comment: Hej aj nad tou alternatívou som rozmýšľal, že dať obrázok do img, ale v css mi to prišlo rýchlejšie a jednoduchšie. Každopádne poprehadzoval som to podľa toho čo si napísal. Všetko vyzerá dobre, ale menu mi zmizlo @EveryScreamer

Comment: ajo no dej tomu menu z-index:1000; třeba

Comment: to je to že dal som a nič stále preč @EveryScreamer

Comment: Ještě top: 0px; left: 0px; :D

Comment: Hej teraz som si všimol, že tým, že som tam dal absolute, tak menu skočilo pod obrázok. To bol hlavný dôvod prečo som dával obrázok cez CSS teraz si spomínam @EveryScreamer

Comment: a mám to díky moc všetko ide ako má :D @EveryScreamer

Comment: Nz, kdyztak polajkuj moje komenty at mam bodíky :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For hero class, remove absolute position and make height 100vh

And also move header module inside .hero
Can check this pen(https://codepen.io/abhii/pen/GRRgwYv)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Restaurant</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="hero">
    <header>
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#">
          <h1>Restaurant</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav__link">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="text">
      <h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum</h1>
      <h3 class="podnadpis">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h3>
      <button class="raise">Lorem ipsum</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <section class="about">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="right">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text evesince the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

```
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:600&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:500&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kalam:700&display=swap");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li,
a {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.logo {
  font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
  color: aliceblue;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 30px 10%;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.hero {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
    ),
    url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/31/19/29/schnitzel-3279045_960_720.jpg");
  // height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  // position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
h1.title {
  color: aliceblue;
  font-family: "Kalam", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 5rem;
}
h3.podnadpis {
  color: aliceblue;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
button {
  color: var(--color);
  transition: 0.25s;
}
button:hover,
button:focus {
  border-color: var(--hover);
  color: #000;
  background-color: #e5ff60;
}
.raise:hover,
.raise:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0.5em 0.5em -0.4em #e5ff60;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.25em);
  transform: translateY(-0.25em);
}
.raise {
  --color: #ffa260;
  --hover: #e5ff60;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

li a {
  transition: all 0.3 ease 0s;
}

li a:hover {
  color: green;
}

section.about {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 30px 10%;
}
p {
  color: #000;
}
.divider {
  width: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
}

.left {
  width: 45%;
  height: auto;
}

.right {
  width: 45%;
  height: auto;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you make use of flexbox image grid
As so:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="column">
    <img src="example1.jpg">
    <img src="example2.jpg">
    <img src="example3.jpg">
  </div>x
  <div class="column">
    <img src="example4.jpg">
    <img src="example5.jpg">
    <img src="example6.jpg">
  </div> 
  <div class="column">
    <img src="example7.jpg">
    <img src="example8.jpg">
    <img src="example9.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="example 10.jpg">
    <img src="example11.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```